# How to activate Privileged Access Groups using Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I am trying to activate my privileged access groups using powershell however so far unable to do so. All the examples either in MS Docs site or google search only have examples regarding instruction to activate roles using powershell for PIM.

Has anyone been successful or have an idea how to get privileged access groups activated using powershell?

Here is what i tried:

```
 #variables
 $upn = ""
 $tenantId = ""
 $reason = "Test"
 $groupId = "" #privileged access groups Id retrieved from Azure Portal > Groups > <group which has roles>
    
 #MFA setup
 if(!(Get-Module | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'PowerShellGet' -and $_.Version -ge '2.2.4.1'})) { Install-Module PowerShellGet -Force }
 if(!(Get-Package msal.ps)) { Install-Package msal.ps }
    
 # Get token for MS Graph by prompting for MFA
 $MsResponse = Get-MSALToken -Scopes @("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default") -ClientId "1b730954-1685-4b74-9bfd-dac224a7b894" -RedirectUri "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" -Authority "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common" -Interactive -ExtraQueryParameters @{claims='{"access_token" : {"amr": { "values": ["mfa"] }}}'}
    
 # Get token for AAD Graph
 $AadResponse = Get-MSALToken -Scopes @("https://graph.windows.net/.default") -ClientId "1b730954-1685-4b74-9bfd-dac224a7b894" -RedirectUri "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" -Authority "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common"
    
 Connect-AzureAD -AadAccessToken $AadResponse.AccessToken -MsAccessToken $MsResponse.AccessToken -AccountId: $upn -tenantId: $tenantId
    
 $roleDefinitionCollection = Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignment -ProviderId "aadRoles" -ResourceId $resource.Id -Filter "subjectId eq '$grouipId'"
    
 #set schedule
 $schedule = New-Object Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.AzureADMSPrivilegedSchedule
 $schedule.Type = "Once"
 $schedule.StartDateTime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ")
 $schedule.endDateTime = (Get-Date).AddHours($activateTime).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ")
        
 $subject = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq '$upn'"
        
 foreach ($roleDefinition in $roleDefinitionCollection) {
     Open-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignmentRequest -ProviderId AadRoles -Schedule $schedule -ResourceId $resource.Id -RoleDefinitionId $roleDefinition.RoleDefinitionId -SubjectId $subject.ObjectId -AssignmentState "Active" -Type "UserAdd" -Reason $reason
 }
```

This returns error message:

```
Open-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignmentRequest : Error occurred while executing OpenAzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignmentRequest
Code: RoleAssignmentDoesNotExist
Message: The Role assignment does not exist.
InnerError:
RequestId: b6e750c4-acf4-4032-84ea-29d74fbc53ac
DateTimeStamp: Fri, 25 Mar 2022 19:00:10 GMT
HttpStatusCode: NotFound
HttpStatusDescription: Not Found
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At line:2 char:5
+ Open-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignmentRequest -ProviderId AadRole ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Open-AzureADMSP...signmentRequest], ApiException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.MSGraphBeta.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.MSGraphBeta.PowerShell.OpenAzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignmentRequest
```

These were some of the sites that i referred: (all only have example to activate the role)
http://www.anujchaudhary.com/2020/02/connect-to-azure-ad-powershell-with-mfa.html
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/powershell-for-azure-ad-roles#activate-a-role-assignment
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OVfwO8_eDjs

Comment: Is this helpful :  https://danielchronlund.com/2021/09/17/activate-your-azure-ad-pim-roles-with-powershell/

Comment: @VineeshVijayan thanks for the link. but my question is related to 'Prvileged Access Groups' which author's powershell module doesn't support: https://danielchronlund.com/2021/09/17/activate-your-azure-ad-pim-roles-with-powershell/#:~:text=Note%3A%20This%20is,complement%20each%20other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: Sorry I misread some part of your question actually.
In fact, you should adapt the provider id to "aadGroups" in order to use the group features.

This should help you to be on track depending on your environment:

```
$groupId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
$upn="myyupn@domain.com"
Connect-AzureAD
$resource = Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedResource -ProviderId aadGroups
$subject = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq '$upn'"

# here you will require some additionnal filtering depending on your environment
$roleDefinitionCollection = Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleDefinition -ProviderId "aadGroups" -ResourceId $groupId

#this works only when pimed in my case:
#$roleDefinitionCollection = Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignment -ProviderId "aadGroups" -ResourceId $resource.id -Filter "ResourceId eq '$groupId' and AssignmentState eq 'Eligible'"
$reason = "test"
foreach ($roleDefinition in $roleDefinitionCollection) {
    $schedule = New-Object Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.AzureADMSPrivilegedSchedule
    $schedule.Type = "Once"
    $schedule.Duration="PT1H"
    $schedule.StartDateTime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ")
    Open-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignmentRequest -ProviderId "aadGroups" -Schedule $schedule -ResourceId $groupId -RoleDefinitionId $roleDefinition.id -SubjectId $subject.ObjectId -AssignmentState "Active" -Type "UserAdd" -Reason $reason
}
```

Comment: You are right, i missed $activateTime and $resource value in my question but those value are set in the code. I missed it while copying and pasting the code. The $activateTime value is set to 'PT1H' and $resource value is: $resource = Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedResource -ProviderId AadRoles
which gets the tenantId. i ran your code and i am getting the same error message as i posted on original question.

Comment: I misread some point and updated my answer. The reason behind your error message "The Role assignment does not exist." is because you need to switch providerId to "aadGroups". Let me know if this suits better to your case

Comment: with the new change, $resource value is array instead of string since it retrieves all PIM AD group so the line where we are getting '$roleDefinitionCollection' errors out with this error message now: Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleDefinition : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'ResourceId'. Specified method is not supported.

Comment: and with this: $roleDefinitionCollection = Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleDefinition -ProviderId "aadGroups" -ResourceId $groupId ?

Comment: lol. that is exactly what i was trying. that does return two values. looping through and trying to run Open-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignmentRequest' gives this error message: Open-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignmentRequest : Error occurred while executing OpenAzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignmentRequest 
Code: RoleAssignmentDoesNotExist'.

Comment: for both requests ? 
If you look at these two values, you should have one for the members, and one for the owners. Depending on which one is your user, this should work for at least one.
Don't forget to run your Open-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignmentRequest with the providerid "aadgroups"

Comment: holy cow. you were right. the error msg i got was for owner but it worked for member. I added if condition within loop to only run when the $roleDefinition.DisplayName is equal to 'Member' and it worked. thanks bunch. 

Answer (score 1):

When you try to assign the Role, it will be

- **You Can't be assigned for a duration of less than five minutes.**
- **You Can't be removed within five minutes of it being assigned**

Here is your script, you need to wait for 5 minutes for every iteration to create a Group Role Assignment

```
foreach ($roleDefinition in $roleDefinitionCollection) {
     Open-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignmentRequest -ProviderId AadRoles -Schedule $schedule -ResourceId $resource.Id -RoleDefinitionId $roleDefinition.RoleDefinitionId -SubjectId $subject.ObjectId -AssignmentState "Active" -Type "UserAdd" -Reason $reason
# wait for 5 minutes 
Start-Sleep -s 300
 }
```

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/groups-assign-member-owner) for more information

Comment: DelliganeshS-MT, in my case the duration of assignment is 1 hou, so i don't think the duration is the issue. Also regarding waiting every 5 mins that might be true, but the loop   errors out on very first assignment so i don't think the time is the factor here.

Comment: Please check the $roleDefinition whether it contains valid definition.

Comment: DelliganeshS-MT it does have value.