# PowerShell or Azure CLI - Show/Create Azure Security Groups with PIM set up

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-cli

Using the Azure Portal, I have set up an Azure Security Group named "SG_AZR-0111-0014-002_O". I then set up Privileged Identity Management to allow PIM to become a member of this group. For background info - I am using this with Azure AD Integration into a third party product, so PIM to become a member of the group will give escalated privileges in the third party product.

I am trying to set up a script - preferably PowerShell or azure cli to automate this as it will be a recurring thing for us (more security groups). I have looked around, but I do not see any way to view and/or create this. As in - I want a script to verify a security group is set up for PIM and if not, create it. Ideally, I'd also like to add members to the eligible assignments.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I want a script to verify a security group is set up for PIM and if not, create it. Ideally, I'd also like to add members to the eligible assignments.

Here is the `PowerShell` script that checks if a security group for `Privileged Identity Management` exists and creates it if it doesn't. It also adds members to the eligible assignments.

```
    Connect-AzureAD
    $upn = "user@acb.onmicrosoft.com"
    $groupId = "xxxxxxxx-21f1-4871-8ba317a7b9b608ee"
    $resource = Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedResource -ProviderId aadGroups
    $subject = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq '$upn'"
    # Check if the security group exists
    $group = Get-AzADGroup -SearchString $securityGroupName
    if ($group -eq $null) {
        # Create the security group if it doesn't exist
        $group = New-AzADGroup -DisplayName $securityGroupName -MailEnabled $false -SecurityEnabled $true
        Write-Host "Created Security Group: $($group.DisplayName)"
    } else {
        Write-Host "The Group: $securityGroupName already exists."
    }
    
    $roleDefinitionCollection = $roleDefinitionCollection = Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleDefinition -ProviderId "aadGroups" -ResourceId $groupId
    $reason = "test"
    
    if ($roleDefinitionCollection.Count -eq 0) {
        $schedule = New-Object Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.AzureADMSPrivilegedSchedule
        $schedule.Type = "Once"
        $schedule.StartDateTime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ")
        
        Open-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignmentRequest -ProviderId AzureResources -Schedule $schedule -ResourceId $securityGroupName -RoleDefinitionId $roleDefinitionId -SubjectId $subjectObjectId -AssignmentState "Eligible" -Type "AdminAdd"
        
        Write-Host "Enabling PIM for the group: $securityGroupName"
    } else {
        Write-Host "PIM is already enabled for the group: $securityGroupName"
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Reference:  [azure - How to activate Privileged Access Groups using Powershell? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71622254/how-to-activate-privileged-access-groups-using-powershell) by `Brice`